# Using a C# class in a VB.NET project

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a `C#` class (a lot of lines).  I want to use this `class` in my `VB.NET` project.
So, I tried to add the `.cs` file to my `VB.NET` project and then call it by:

`MyclassName.VoidName()`

It's not working.

(`'MycalssName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`)

How can I use a `C#` `class` in my `VB.NET` project?

Comment: Add a reference to the C# project in your VB.NET project. Then you can access the classes via Namespace.ClassName.

Comment: If the c# code is compilable, `Tim Schmelter`'s comment is your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply compile  `C#` code into an assembly (DLL) and reference that assembly from your `VB.NET` project.

Answer (score 0):

A single .NET assembly/project should contain code written in one supported language only. Compilation of any .NET project will need the language specific MSBuild targets (which are included as part of the project files). So, you will be unable to compile/use a C# language source file in a VB.net project and vice versa.

Ignoring the MSBUild aspects, the compilation of a vb.net project (with a c# source file) will not even suceed, as the syntax will be different and compiler (vbc.exe) will throw a lot of compiler errors.

So, its best to compile the C# project and refer to the types from the VB.net project.